# Statistical test for comparing bimodal distributions in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have data that follows bimodal distribution and looks as follows:

```r
# Install and load the ggplot2 package
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

# Example data 
distribution1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
distribution2 <- c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24)

# Combine data into a data frame
data <- data.frame(value = c(distribution1, distribution2),
                   distribution = rep(c("Distribution 1", 
                    "Distribution 2"), each = 10))

# Plot density using ggplot2
ggplot(data, aes(x = value, fill = distribution)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(title = "Bimodal Distributions",
       x = "Values",
       y = "Density") +
  theme_minimal()
```

What statistical test should I do to check if the two distributions are significantly different or not? My understanding is that mann whitney will not work since that uses medians.

Comment: The mann whitney is a rank sum test, and not a test of difference in medians. This is a common misconception. It can be used in this use case.

Comment: Do you actually have 10 data points, or is this just an example

Comment: my sample size for both the distributions is 500